# Using @FocusState variables in NavigationLink View makes this view return back instantly to the previous view

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, navigationview, property-wrapper

I have `SignUpView` divided across two smaller views. Both of them connected in `NavigationView` of the first one. `NavigationLink` in the first view leads to the second one. I tried using iOS 15 [`@FocusState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate/) property wrappers to variables and `.focused` modifier to some Text Fields. All actions with those variables works properly in the first view, however when I go to the second view via `NavigationLink` it instantly returns to the first view with nothing there entered as if the view has been cleared out. This only happens when I'm using `.focused` modifier in the second view along with some actions connected with variables with `@FocusState` property wrappers.

The usage of `@FocusState variables` along with `.focused modifier`
In the first View:

```swift
@State var email: String = ""
@State var password: String = ""

@FocusState private var isEmailTextFieldFocused: Bool
@FocusState private var isPasswordTextFieldFocused: Bool

TextField("E-mail", text: $email)
    .focused($isEmailTextFieldFocused)
    .onSubmit {
        isEmailTextFieldFocused = false
        isPasswordTextFieldFocused = true
    }

SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    .focused($isPasswordTextFieldFocused)
    .onSubmit {
        isPasswordTextFieldFocused = false
    }
```

In the second View:

```swift
@State private var email: String = ""
@State private var password: String = ""
@State private var repeatedPassword: String = ""

@FocusState private var isEmailTextFieldFocused: Bool
@FocusState private var isPasswordTextFieldFocused: Bool
@FocusState private var isRepeatedPasswordTextFieldFocused: Bool

TextField("E-mail", text: $email, onCommit: {
    Task {
        self.emailTaken = try await signUpViewModel.checkEmailDuplicate(email: email)
    }
})
    .focused($isEmailTextFieldFocused)
    .onSubmit {
        isEmailTextFieldFocused = false
        isPasswordTextFieldFocused = true
        isRepeatedPasswordTextFieldFocused = false
    }

SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    .focused($isPasswordTextFieldFocused)
    .onSubmit {
        isEmailTextFieldFocused = false
        isPasswordTextFieldFocused = false
        isRepeatedPasswordTextFieldFocused = true
    }

SecureField("Confirm Password", text: $repeatedPassword)
    .disableAutocorrection(true)
    .autocapitalization(.none)
    .focused($isRepeatedPasswordTextFieldFocused)
    .onSubmit {
        isEmailTextFieldFocused = false
        isPasswordTextFieldFocused = false
        isRepeatedPasswordTextFieldFocused = false
    }
```

Comment: Try to use `.focused(, value:)` instead of two bools

Comment: @Asperi You might be talking about `.focused(, equals: )`, right? Unfortunately introducing hashable enum with TextFields and then using the above version of .focused modifier (like in official Apple Developer Documentation) did not help.